# Get an access to OpenShift nodes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, nodes

I have Openshift Cluster on OpenShift Container Platform. I can't get list of nodes.

```
oc get nodes
```

And I'm getting such error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "isupportal"
> cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

```
oc version
```

> Client Version: 4.8.0-202206281335.p0.g7c3760e.assembly.stream-7c3760e 
> Kubernetes Version: v1.21.11+6b3cbdd

### How to get the list of nodes?

Comment: The user `isupportal` is not having `RBAC` permissions to list nodes. You will have to create RBAC permissions by asking your admin.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the reason you cannot get information about the nodes is because you do not have permissions to do so. Access to everything is via role based access control.

For example, you may have the `basic-user` permission, based on what you are showing us. This is the definition of `basic-user`:

```
➜oc describe clusterrole basic-user
Name:         basic-user
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  openshift.io/description: A user that can get basic information about projects.
              rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
PolicyRule:
  Resources                                           Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                                           -----------------  --------------  -----
  selfsubjectrulesreviews                             []                 []              [create]
  selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io       []                 []              [create]
  selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.openshift.io  []                 []              [create]
  clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io              []                 []              [get list watch]
  volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io       []                 []              [get list watch]
  clusterroles                                        []                 []              [get list]
  clusterroles.authorization.openshift.io             []                 []              [get list]
  storageclasses.storage.k8s.io                       []                 []              [get list]
  users                                               []                 [~]             [get]
  users.user.openshift.io                             []                 [~]             [get]
  projects                                            []                 []              [list watch]
  projects.project.openshift.io                       []                 []              [list watch]
  projectrequests                                     []                 []              [list]
  projectrequests.project.openshift.io                []                 []              [list]
```

You will notice that no where in there is permissions for node. So you will not have permission to list or get information about the nodes. Whereas, the default user `cluster-reader` does. (I'm not going to give the whole list, because it is long.)

```
➜oc describe clusterrole cluster-reader |grep nodes
  nodes/stats                                                   []                 []              [create get]
  nodes/status                                                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  nodes                                                         []                 []              [get list watch]
  nodes.metrics.k8s.io                                          []                 []              [get list watch]
  csinodes.storage.k8s.io                                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  nodes/metrics                                                 []                 []              [get]
  nodes/spec                                                    []                 []              [get]
```

So, as mentioned in the comments, you will have to ask your admin for additional permissions if you want to be able to run `oc get nodes`. `cluster-reader` is a good place to start, but your admin may have custom roles defined beyond the default ones.